# How to solve mismatch fragment

Tags: kotlin, mismatch, why3

I intend to write permission in Fragment Kotlin. I have found a simple code for activity and decided to convert into my fragment but I have a error "mismatch". Can you assist me to solve this issue?[text](https://stackoverflow.com)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXhx7.png)

I have thought to initialize new context for this fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you could replace **this** keyword with **requireActivity()**